# Django Redirect not updating page

Tags: django, django-forms

I am having an issue with successfully calling a redirect after a user tries to log in (successful or unsuccessfully). In the console, I did notice that the GET and POST statements are correct. Thank You all in advance as this is a becoming a royal PIA.

**views.py**

```
class UserLoginFormView(View):
form_class = UserLoginForm
template_name = 'home/login.html'

#Display Blank Form
def get(self,request):
    form = self.form_class(None)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

#Process Form Data
def post(self,request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        return redirect('products')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.HomeView, name='home'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name="register"),
    url(r'^login/$', views.UserLoginFormView.as_view(), name="user_login"),
    url(r'^products/$', views.ProductsView, name="products"),
]
```

**login.html**

```
<form class="cozy" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group control">
        <label for="username" class="control-label">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group control">
        <label for="password" class="control-label">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
    </div>

    {% if form.errors %}
    <p class=" label label-danger">
        Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.
    </p>
    {% endif %}

    <div class="d-flex align-content-center justify-content-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-accent">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Console Output**

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 25, 2019 - 15:39:24
Django version 1.11.18, using settings 'svcreporter.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:9000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[25/Jan/2019 15:39:28] "GET /home/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4490
[25/Jan/2019 15:39:34] "POST /home/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[25/Jan/2019 15:39:34] "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 17242
```

Comment: The console log indicates that when POST was called, it returned a 302 redirect, followed immediately by a GET on /home/.  Isn't that what you want?  What actual problem are you having?  Telling us you "have an issue" isn't very specific.

Comment: My apologies, I am not being redirected after being logged in. It just sits at login.html

Comment: You don't have a url defined for `/home/`.  How is that url even being served?

Comment: from my understanding that is what the first URL pattern is doing: url(r'^$', views.HomeView, name='home'),

Comment: No, that's defining the empty root url, i.e. just `/`.

Comment: it is defining the root url to home/ which is where I am trying to redirect the user to. At least that is what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `as_view()` part in:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.HomeView, name='home'),
    # ...
]
```

it should be:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    # ... 
]
```

and I would say that in some point you'll be struggling with this too:

```
# Add .as_view() to views.ProductsView
url(r'^products/$', views.ProductsView, name="products")
```

Comment: Thanks, But this still does not resolve the problem.